# Spock's tests are unsuccessful after being launched by Maven

Tags: java, maven, spock

Tests succeed when run standalone (in IDE) but throws: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException` when fired via Maven

I debugged `mvn test` and found out that `gameObject` has no fields defined at runtime when being fired via Maven. The concrete exception message is:

`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: gameObject for class: org.monterinio.games.asteroids.player.view.PlayerView`

Test folder: `src/test/groovy`

Contains (among others)                 org.monterinio.games.asteroids.player.controller.action.BasicActionHandlerTest

Src folder: `src/main/java`

Contains (among others):

```
package org.monterinio.games.asteroids.player.view;

public class PlayerView extends GameObjectView {

  public Player player;

  public PlayerView(Node view, Player gameObject) {
      super(view);
      this.player = gameObject;
  }
}


package org.monterinio.games.asteroids.player.model;

public class Player extends GameObject {

  private String name;
  private double angle;
  private List<Bullet> bullets;
  private AbstractMovementSignals movementSignals;
  private AbstractRotationSignals rotationSignals;
  private AbstractActionSignals actionSignals;

  public Player(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.movementSignals = new BasicMovementSignals();
    this.rotationSignals = new BasicRotationSignals();
    this.actionSignals = new BasicActionSignals();
    this.bullets = new ArrayList<>();
  }
}
```

My current `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.airhacks</groupId>
        <artifactId>afterburner.fx</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- TEST -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>testfx-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.15-alpha</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>testfx-spock</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.15-alpha</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- FOR MOCKING IN SPOCK -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>dashboard.fxml</include>
                <include>dashboard.css</include>
            </includes>
            <targetPath>org/monterinio/games/asteroids</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <configuration>
                <testSourceDirectory>src/test/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                    <!-- Yes, .java extension -->
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <!-- Just in case having "normal" JUnit tests -->
                </includes>
                <argLine>--illegal-access=deny</argLine>
                <argLine>--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gmaven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Without joint compilation - no dependencies between Java and Groovy (inheritance)-->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.monterinio.games.asteroids.MainAsteroids</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I expect the tests will be successful when being executed by Maven.

Comment: Well? I don't actually see any property named `gameObject` anywhere, and that's even presuming that you have getters and setters you omitted. I see a `player` *field*, although that should probably be a `private final` backing field for a property.

Comment: Oh, good point. However, neither changing to `player` nor setting it to `private final` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: IIRC groovy still uses some reflection so you might run into issues with `--illegal-access=deny`

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can all see, compile and run your code. Missing classes and incomplete POMs are not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Opening packages which are being tested solved the problem:

`package.info`

```
...
// needs to be opened for testing
opens org.monterinio.games.asteroids.player.model;
opens org.monterinio.games.asteroids.player.model.rotation;
...
```

Or simply opening the whole module:

```
open module asteroids {
  ...
}
```